# tkinter best way to adjust absolute coordinates based on native resolution

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Presently I have my code which places a window on a canvas using 
create_window((x,y),anchor="nw",....). I see how it displays (on a 1920x1080 monitor)and have adjusted x,y accordingly. But, when I then ran it on a 1360x768 screen it does not look good. So, I adjusted x,y (using the method to get screen width/height) and using different values for (x,y) based on that.
Is this the normal way to do that ?  Because I have several places in my code for other calculations where I have to make this explicit adjustment. I am wondering if there is some better way to do this ?

Comment: So you want it always fullscreen?

Comment: Yes. my application will be full screen. No resizing of any window  by user. Thanks

Comment: So did the solution from TidB not work?

Comment: I was already using the fullscreen (since I did not want the toolbar etc). so that did not work. I am now trying to redesign the code to purely use the geometry managers and see if I can get it to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

As ProgrammingIsAwsome mentioned in the comments, I think you want your application to be in fullscreen mode. There are two different ways to do this (assuming `root` is a `tk.Tk()` instance):

The first way is actually a maximized window:

```
self.root.state("zoomed")
```

The second is the real fullscreen mode, hiding the taskbar and title bar:

```
self.root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
```

Furthermore, I wouldn't recommend doing anything with absolute sizes. Use the nice geometry managers `grid` and `place` which manage that for you.

Comment: I do use self.root.attributes("-fullscreen", True). I have used grid for table like grids in my application and pack other places where it made sense. The application itself works fine except for this. The thing is that when I run it in these two different resolutions. Maybe if this is never going to work I have to see a way to rework to use purely the geometry managers. But somehow using the canvas create window placing some widgets using the x,y worked and I just realized the catch.

Comment: it sounds like you need to look into using the geometry managers own resizing functions to allow your program to resize gracefully, for instance with grid you can assign each column or row a weighting to determine how much it will expand with a change in window size, from experience its best to first create the interface at the smallest size you wish it to be used, and then look at how it expands.